# Searching for an item within a ListBox using a TextBox and a Button

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a system that includes a `ListBox` of integers inserted by the user. I have contained a search button and a search `TextBox` for the user to input the integer they want to search for within the `ListBox`. Once the user has inputted the integer, I want a message box to be displayed either informing the user that there is e.g. 1 integer of value '3' in the list box, or an error message box informing the user that the integer does not exist within the list box.

```
private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxAddedIntegers.SelectedItems.Clear();
    for (int i = listBoxAddedIntegers.Items.Count - 1;i>=0; i--) ;
    {
        if (listBoxAddedIntegers.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(textBoxSearch.Text.ToLower())) ;
        {
            listBoxAddedIntegers.SetSelected(i, true);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

I am not really sure on the code that I am meant to include here, and the code that I have already inserted suggests that 'i' does not exist in the current content.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: remove the ; after the for line ```for (int i = listBoxAddedIntegers.Items.Count - 1;i>=0; i--); ``` its evil and also represents the body of the for loop, so the block after that isnt recognized the way, you want it to. so its no wonder, that i isnt known either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxAddedIntegers.SelectedItems.Clear();

        var itemsFound = listBoxAddedIntegers.Items.Where(i=>i.ToString().ToLower().Contains(textBoxSearch.Text.ToLower())).ToList();

        if(itemsFound == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No matches found.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Found " + itemsFound.Count + " matches.");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> the code that I have already inserted suggests that 'i' does not exist in the current content

As [@FrankM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1037841/frankm) already mentioned in the comments. You have a trailing `;` after your `for`-loop.

```
for (int i = listBoxAddedIntegers.Items.Count - 1;i>=0; i--) ;
```

This will prevent the `for`-loop to execute your code within the `{ ... }`. This can be transcribed to

```
for (int i = listBoxAddedIntegers.Items.Count - 1;i>=0; i--)
{
    // Do nothing.
}
{
   // now your code
}
```

This means also that your code within the last curly braces will be in its own scope and so that all your defined variables will be unavailable to the following code.

---

**Answering your actual question:**

As you already do for selecting the matching items. You can extent this looping by counting up a counter. And later on show the results with a [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx).

With the following snippet of your code

```
listBoxAddedIntegers.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(textBoxSearch.Text.ToLower()))
```

you are currently checking if an item of your list contains the entered `TextBox.Text`.
So if the user has entered *3, 4, 5, ..., 13,  23* in the `ListBox` and searches for *3*. He will get 3 matches. If you want only 1 match you should use [`String.Equals()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals(v=vs.110).aspx). I used [`StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid calling `ToLower()`.

```
private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.listBoxAddedIntegers.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = this.listBoxAddedIntegers.Items[i];
        if (string.Equals(item.ToString(), this.textBoxSearch.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            this.listBoxAddedIntegers.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    if (counter == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"No matches for \"{this.textBoxSearch.Text}\" found!", "Search Results",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"{counter} items found for \"{this.textBoxSearch.Text}\"!", "Search Results",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

---

*Hint:

Since C#6 you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) instead of [String.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) or string concatenation (+).*

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```
int count=0;

for(int i=0;i<listBoxAddedIntegers.Items.Count;i++)
{
    if(listBoxAddedIntegers.Items[i].Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(textBoxSearch.Text.ToLower())
    {
         count+=1;     
    }
}

if(count>0)
{
     //display your message here after the loop with the count
}
else
{
     //display your message with error
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this answer was very useful to me. However, on the first message box after the count, I can only get it to display the actual text that is inputted into the search text box, when i want it to display something like "There is 1 item 'July' in the list box."?

Comment: You can customize the message by doing something like this, "There is"+count+"item ' "+(whatever the name is you want to display)+"' in the ListBox". Do mark this answer as correct if the answer helped you and upvote it !