# Shuffling the items in a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a system that contains integers in a `ListBox`. I have included a 'Shuffle' `Button`, which should shuffle the stored items in the `ListBox` into a random order, when clicked by the user.

However, the code I am using is not working for this. Has anyone got any suggestions on how to generate a shuffle button to randomize the data within a `ListBox`?

Comment: ```buttonShuffle.ObjectCollection``` ->```ObjectCollection```
not sure what you want to achieve, but ```Listbox.Items``` has the class ```ObjectCollection```

Comment: You didn't even specify the UI technology you are using; how can you expect someone to help you?

Comment: @UweKeim added [tag:winforms] due to related question [Searching for an item within a ListBox using a TextBox and a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47696447/5893316).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you store this in a variable of type `buttonShuffle.ObjectCollection`.

Just access the `Items` property of the ListBox:

```
while (n > 1)
{
    n--;
    int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
    object value = listBoxAddedIntegers.Items[k];
    listBoxAddedIntegers.Items[k] = listBoxAddedIntegers.Items[n];
    listBoxAddedIntegers.Items[n] = value;
}
```

If you did it because you wanted a shorter name, use `ListBox.ObjectCollection` or `var`:

```
var items = this.listBoxAddedIntegers.Items;

while (n > 1)
{
    n--;
    int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
    object value = items[k];
    items[k] = items[n];
    items[n] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your life a bit easier, use a `DataTable` to hold your list items, give it another column that you can sort:

```
//this is a class wide variable
DataTable _d = new DataTable();

//in your constructor
_d.Columns.Add("DisplayThis");
_d.Columns.Add("SortThis", typeof(int));

_d.DefaultView.Sort = "[SortThis] ASC";

yourListBox.DataSource = _d.DefaultView;
yourListBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayThis";

//in your method that formerly loaded the listbox items
Random r = new Random();
foreach(string s in yourListItemsToDisplayArray) 
  d.Rows.Add(new object[] { s, (int)r.Next(1000) }); 

//or if the listbox is to show numbers
Random r = new Random();
foreach(int i in yourListItemsToDisplayArray) 
  d.Rows.Add(new object[] { i.ToString(), (int)r.Next(1000) });
```

And every time you want to shuffle them, just pass over the datatable, changing the numbers:

```
//your shuffle button click handler
shuffleButton_Click(object sender, ClickEventArgs e){
  Random r = new Random();
  foreach(var ro in _d.Rows)
    ro["SortThis"] = r.Next(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
buttonShuffle.ObjectCollection list = listBoxAddedIntegers.Items;
```

makes no sense.  The compiler will be trying to create a variable called `list` of type `buttonShuffle.ObjectCollection`, which I'm assuming is not a valid type.

I *think* what you need to do is make `list` a `List<int>` (or `var`), and then populate `buttonShuffle.ObjectCollection` from `list` at the end of your method, using whatever method is appropriate for that operation (Add, AddRange, etc)

Comment: Well, it sorta could, if there was a namespace called buttonShuffle that wasn't imported, and had an ObjectCollection class?

Comment: @CaiusJard I applaud your pedantry :)  But I think it is unlikely to be the case.  If it is then I've had it with helping

Comment: Every time you make something idiotproof, you know what the universe does... :)